# Help me determine what to plant here

Tags: grass

I have a small pathway made of natural sandstone pavers and I'm looking for the best "fillers" to plant in the spaces between them. I was thinking of using [polymeric sand](https://www.thespruce.com/what-is-polymeric-sand-2132510) but my wife has suggested using grass to keep it looking softer. We live in zone 5 (Denver area) but the pathway is on the south side of the house and gets very hot and is in bright sun most of the day. What kind of grass would be best here? Any other suggestions or comments?

Thanks!

edits:
Our soil is dense clay.
Here is a picture I meant to add earlier:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Stormy, your idea of Woolly Thyme is interesting but grass seed has a certain easy to plant aspect about it. How would I get WT to spread throughout the cracks (see picture) it I have to plant individual plants?

Answer (score 1):

Do what your wife suggests.  That sand is essentially concrete and it will look horrible.  I would entertain Woolly Thyme.  Soft, very very tough little plant.  Should do well in Denver.  When the stones get hot walking on the thyme is so nice and fragrant.

White grout or white sand or white anything between stones is not 'cool'...aesthetically.

Grass would be tougher to maintain unless you were excellent with a line trimmer.  If it gets that hot, grass roots will not be happy. Are these stones in the body of a larger lawn?  Then definitely you want to use the same grass as the lawn.

Otherwise, Woolly Thyme actually shades its own soil to protect its roots somewhat.  During the hottest days if this ever becomes a problem, I would have some row cloth or Reemay on hand to whip out and cover the walkway to reflect heat, hold in moisture.  And that would be for any plant planted between stones, pavers that absorb the heat and transfer it to the soil. I would think Denver wouldn't get so hot to not allow planting between flagstones.  Arizona sure...

Do you have an irrigation system?  Too much water is not good for Woolly thyme.
What are you using for fertilizer?

Woolly thyme (there are lots of 'Stepables' in nurseries these days) can and will deal with hot summers and cold winters.  I've tested it...grins!!  Do not cave and get one of each kind of Stepables' to bring home and test.  You want a mass planting of one plant only.  Aesthetics of course, but these Stepables are major gnarly weeds in the first place.  Sandstone slabs and woolly thyme would be breathtaking.  If you've got over 60' of walkway you could get by with one other species.  No periwinkle allowed.  Careful with most Speedwell and violets.